# Spyder 4.2.5 - iPython Console Not Working With Python 3.8.0

Tags: ipython, spyder, python-3.8

I have installed Python 3.8 & Spyder 4.2.5 on Windows 10 machine. I have changed the Python Interpreter from default to 3.8. After making these changes , iPython console is showing the following error

**Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 1.10.0 and < 1.11.0)). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.
You can install it by running in a system terminal:
`conda install spyder‑kernels or pip install spyder‑kernels`**

So, i have closed the Spyder IDE, executed the commands for installing spyder-kernels and restarted the Spyder but still i am getting the same error. Please check the image below

[image]

Can you please suggest a solution on how to fix the error?

Comment: To make this a bit more specific: are you using `conda` or `pip`? Is your Python installation the same that you installed Spyder to?

Comment: @MrFuppes I am using pip for installing the spyder-kernels. Python that i have installed on my machine is 3.8.0 whereas spyder is using different version so i have changed the settings in python interpreter available in Spyder to use 3.8.0 version of python instead of default version provided by spyder

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, fixed it by pip-installing a specific version of spyder-kernels to that Python environment (as the error says, e.g. `pip install spyder-kernels==1.10.0`). Important point here is to make sure you install to the correct env.  Side note: you might want to have a look at [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win) to manage your Python environments; I find that tool pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with Spyder 5.1.4 when I changed python interpreter from default python that's installed with Spyder to a my own python installation v3.9.5.

And every time I execute the command **pip install spyder-kernels**.
It show the message:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"d:\program\python\python39\python.exe" "d:\program\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install spyder-kernels': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My solution is **python3 -m pip install spyder-kernels==2.1.1**

You can find the compatible kernel version of your spyder in this link and replace it with 2.1.1

http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/common-illnesses.html#spyder-kernels-not-installed-incompatible

Hope it's helpful to someone!